# Python - Accessing items inside a list from text file

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to apply validation for the items in a list. I have managed to open it but am struggling trying to compare if the two words are anagrams.

This is my result in the terminal.

```
anagram:  ['word,word', 'stiff,schtiff', 'word,word', 'stiff,schtiff', 'word,word', 'stiff,schtiff', 'word,word', 'stiff,schtiff']

Anagram
```

In this sample, it is clear I am doing it wrong with the two identical variables A, B but am not sure what to do.

```
word1 = open('a.txt', 'r').read().split()
word2 = open('a.txt', 'r').read().split()
count = {}
validation = True
if len(a) == len(b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] in count:
            count[a[i]] += 1
        else:
            count[a[i]] = 1  
        if b[i] in count:
            count[b[i]] += 1
        else:
            count[b[i]] = 1     
    for i in count:
        if count[i] % 2 == 0:
            validation = "Anagram"
        else:
            validation = "Not Anagram"
            break
else:
    validation = "Not Anagram"            
print(validation)
```

What the hell am I doing?

I want to achieve this in the terminal.

```
anagram:  ['word,word', 'stiff,schtiff', 'word,word', 'stiff,schtiff', 'word,word', 'stiff,schtiff', 'word,word', 'stiff,schtiff']

anagram, not anagram, anagram, not anagram, anagram, not anagram, anagram, not anagram
```

Comment: Perhaps provide what you want to achieve with an expected result.

Comment: Done. See above ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to to that:

```
anagram = ['word,word', 'stiff,schtiff', 'word,word', 'stiff,schtiff', 'word,word', 'stiff,schtiff', 'word,word', 'stiff,schtiff']
for elem in anagram:
    items = elem.split(",")
    firstLetters = set(items[0])
    secondLetters = set(items[1])
    if firstLetters == secondLetters:
        print("Anagram")
    else:
        print("Not anagram")
```

Output:

```
Anagram
Not anagram
Anagram
Not anagram
Anagram
Not anagram
Anagram
Not anagram
```

**Edit:** Here is how you can read them from file and perform comparisons:

```
with open("anagram.txt","r") as inFile:
    words = [line for line in inFile]
    words = words[0].strip().split(",")
    first = []
    second = []
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            first.append(words[i])
        else:
            second.append(words[i])
    for f,s in zip(first,second):
        if set(f) == set(s):
            print("Anagram")
        else:
            print("Not anagram")
```

Comment: The data set is being read from a text file. This is what I am finding difficult.

Comment: So how do you get the elements for `anagram`? If you could provide some sample data for both files then I could be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I retrieve them by opening the file in the text editor. The code reads the list which is inside the text file: a = open('anagram.txt', 'r').read().split()

Comment: Sorry. I have a separate part that prints out the list: anagramlist = open('anagram.txt', 'r').read().split() print(anagramlist)

Comment: As you can see, I have duplicated (which I know is wrong), but don't know how to do this properly.

Comment: So the list in the file is stored like this: `anagram: [...,...,...]`?

Comment: Just like this: `word,word,stiff,schtiff...`

Comment: And you want to compare every two words?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to achieve. We could move this to chat but I haven't got enough "rep" to do so.

Comment: The file contains these: `word,word,stiff,schtiff,word,word,stiff,schtiff,word,word,stiff,schtiff,word,word,stiff,schtiff`

Comment: Ah yes. It appears I accidentally altered the original notepad file when I was making mistakes. This has really helped me, thank you